# Unable to access SAMBA from domain workstations

Tags: samba

I have a rather interesting problem, hopefully someone here may be able to point me in the right direction in order to solve it.

Basics:

- Windows 2003 R2 Domain
- Windows XP SP3 Pro Workstation joined to said domain
- Windows XP SP3 Pro Workstation NOT joined to said domain but on same network, just not a domain member computer.
- OpenSUSE 11.2 SAMBA SHARE

Now the problem is this.

The NON-JOINED Workstation can access the SAMBA share via IP and/or HOSTNAME.  The joined computer can not and receives the following message:

"Windows cannot find '\\10.0.0.15'.  Check the spelling and try again, or try search for the item by clicking the Start button and then clicking Search."

I'm a little confused.  Both computers (and domain) are connected to the same switch, access the same firewall and run the same software.  The only difference is that one computer is a member of a domain, the other is not.

The GPO for the domain has many options.  Are there some security options that I have setup that could be causing this problem?

Note : The Samba share is 100% setup correctly, does not access the domain, does not care about the domain, is not a member, and works for non domain joined computers on the same network.

Update : All firewalls (on samba box, windows xp boxes, domain) are off.  There is no firewall between the SAMBA box and the windows machines.  (to just clear that up now)

Update #2 :  Here is not only the global section, but my entire smb.conf

```
[global]
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        printcap cache time = 750
        cups options = raw
        map to guest = Bad User
        usershare allow guests = No
        domain logons = No
        domain master = No
        security = user
        netbios name = mctdev
        passdb backend = smbpasswd
        server name = MCTDEV
        server string = MCTDEV
        comment = MCTDEV
        workgroup = MCTSHINE


[dump]
        comment = Dump
        inherit acls = Yes
        path = /srv/dump
        read only = No
        force group = dump
        force user = dump
        guest ok = Yes
        username = dump
```

Comment: Can you post some of the [global] section of your smb.conf?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state the version of Samba you're using....

> The GPO for the domain has many options. Are there some security options that I have setup that could be causing this problem?

**Short answer:** Yes.
Most likely is a setting that requires high security settings (such as encryption, SPNEGO etc.) for all connections to shares of remote fileservers.

**Longer answer:**
I also noted that your `[dump]` share requests `username = dump` as the connecting username for the clients. An AD member client machine will always supply the current user's domain account name for each initial connection request to a remote fileserver. I assume this one is not *dump*. That would mean, Samba sees a *bad user*, which it will `map to guest` per quoted smb.conf. So, the question is: ***is*** there a guest account on your Samba system?

**Advice:**
Temporarily add settings of `log level = 3` (you can increase to 10 if you like verbose logs) and `log file = /tmp/smbd.log.%m` to your `[global]` section in smb.conf. That should give you some clues about what ***Samba*** sees happening, once you investigate your `smbd.log.*` files. Each client will have its own logfile, and you can easily compare what's the difference between connection attempts by AD and by non-AD clients.